# Using enum as id

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Using JPA, can we define an enum as id of an entity?

I've tried the following:

```
public enum AssetType {
   ....
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AssetType.class)
public class Adkeys {

   private AssetType type;

   @Id
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(nullable = false)
   public AssetType getType() {
      return type;
   }

}
```

Using OpenJPA, it complains:

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The id class "class aa.AssetType" specified by type "class aa.Adkeys" does not have a public no-args constructor.

So my questions are:

- should we able to use enum as id for an entity on JPA? (i.e. there is a bug in OpenJPA)
- or do I make a mistake somewhere?
- and is there any workaround for such problem?

Comment: @Nathan: So then it has to be a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JPA spec doesn't say this is possible:

> 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> The primary key (or field or property of a composite primary key) should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; java.lang.String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date. In general, however, approximate numeric types (e.g., floating point types) should never be used in primary keys. Entities whose primary keys use types other than these will not be portable.

If you really want to have a compile-time fixed number of records for a given entity, you can use a `String` or `int` primary key and assign it `AssetType.FOO.name()` or `AssetType.FOO.ordinal()`

And non-portable here means that some persistence provider may support other things, but it might not work for another provider. As with the enum - if the persistence provider has special support for it, that does not try to instantiate it, but rather processes it specially after checking if `class.isEnum()`, then it might work. But it seems your persistence provider doesn't do this.

Comment: It doesn't say this is possible but doesn't say it is impossible either. It just says: 'Entities whose primary keys use types other than these will not be portable'. In fact, it doesn't also say that a class can be used as primary key but it's possible.

Comment: that's another thing - an embeddable id. see my update for the portability part.

Comment: so I guess this is a valid request for an enhancement, don't you think?

Comment: @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) doesn't this mean that the column is persisted as string value? Yes it is, so it should be possible to use it as an @Id column.
There are situations where there are not many entries in the table, and you need to reference by string.
Numeric Id is the most used way, but other data types are not wrong if used correctly!

Comment: Adding the link to the source of truth would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't use enums as ID because JPA doesn't allow to define your own mapping for ID columns (they must be `int` or `long` or something that JPA can create with `new`).

IDs must not be the business key (in your case: the type). Using the business key as an ID is a common mistake in DB designs and should be avoided because it will cause all kinds of problems later.

Add an independent ID column to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm working with old database. It might be not good design but it's there. The enum is just a bunch of rigid value.

Answer (score 3):

OpenJPA is the only JPA provider that does not support this.
See [Support Enum as Primary Key Type](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1541)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to do this? This construct doesn't allow changing the database enum keys without updating the enum in the code (fail on load), nor the other way around (constraint failure). Why don't you just create an AssetType table with int pk and name, and make the Adkeys have a foreign key to AssetType.id as pk?

You can load the AssetTypes from the db on startup if you need to enumerate them in your app.

Comment: I'm working with old database. Of course I can change it but it might be problematic. The enum is just a bunch of rigid value.