# JPA using `Enum` as an `@Id` with `@IdClass`

Tags: jpa

I found a forum with this subject. [Using enum as id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717694)

But I couldn't sure that I can do it or not. I think my case is a little bit different.

```java
enum Type {
}

class MyEntityId {
    String type;
    String key;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(MyEntityId.class)
class MyEntity {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
    @Id
    Type type;

    @Id
    String key;
}
```

Is this actually legal by the spec?
If it is, can I have no worries for vendor specific behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not read the linked issue ? It quotes the spec (2.1.4) and says NO you cannot have id fields of Enum type; it doesn't matter that you have some (invalid) IdClass (since the types of an IdClass have to match the types of the class). So it is not part of the JPA spec, so you are left with vendor-specific behaviour.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2016?

Comment: It is still valid as of the latest version of Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate 4 you can use an Enum as an `@Id` in an `IdClass`, but only as an Ordinal. Any `@Convert` tags you add the the enumeration will be ignored.

What you can do is use an `@EmbeddedId` to get the same effect

```
@Embeddable
class MyEntityId {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
    Type type;
    String key;
}

@Entity
class MyEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    MyEntityId id;
}
```